# I have to copy some particular data in excel using macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have to copy data in excel from `B5:L16`  and paste it in another worksheet on `C3:M14`. I have the below code which copies the entire sheet. I am not able to identify the correct cell number.

```
Set wkbImportedWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook
Set wksImportedWorksheet = wkbImportedWorkbook.Sheets("Summary")


Set rngImportCopyRange = Range(wksImportedWorksheet.Cells(1, 1), Cells(5000, 1)).EntireRow
rngImportCopyRange.Copy wksMasterWorksheet.Cells(1, 1)


rngImportCopyRange.Copy
wksMasterWorksheet.Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False

wkbMasterWorkbook.Activate
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
wkbImportedWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

wksMasterWorksheet.Activate
wksMasterWorksheet.Cells(1, 1).Select

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: What you describe would be (in one line) `Worksheets("source").Range("B5:L16").Copy Worksheets("destination").Range("C3:M14")` So there are several possibilities (a) that is what you were looking for (b) your description of your issue is too bad (c) It's very unclear what you are trying to do with that code. Please [edit] and improve your question, ask a clear question, describe what actually happens and what you expected instead. Much more information is needed.

Comment: I have some data in Sheet 1 and I have to select some particular amount as the data present in cell range from `B5:L16` and I have to paste that data in a different worksheet in `C3:M14`

Comment: You are just repeating yourself. The code I posted in my first comment does exactly that. You just need to change the worksheet names.

Comment: Getting error9 subscription out of range

Comment: With your variables `wksImportedWorksheet.Range("B5:L16").Copy: wksMasterWorksheet.Range("C3:M14").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues` is all you need to copy